# Create Custom STS service

Tags: wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I'am looking at the capabilities of WIF in terms of SSO. Actually we have a "legacy" users & rights management database under SQLServer and we like to build a brand new SSO system on top of this exsting database.

In many tutorials I found they talk about using existing STS like ADFSv2 for Active Directory authorization, but It did not fit my needs because my users/rights are not exposed through AD but in a custom a specific business oriented SQL Server database.

So, I thing I need a custom Security Token Service in order to be able to emit my own custom tokens, but I don't know how to do this.

I need some little help or an example about how to achieve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find STS example in WIF SDK. It contain an example with custom token. Look [here](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=4451)
More detail information about SSO I seen in a book '[Programming Windows Identity Foundation](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FProgramming-Identity-Foundation-Developer-Reference%2Fdp%2F0735627185&ei=krUSVf3zI4SAzAP_3IGQBQ&usg=AFQjCNHNeOagf20iXvV03bdDEwZ_jGtI3w&sig2=QF8rOTkeo1BXQtDg3hSK7w&bvm=bv.89184060,d.bGQ)'

Comment: The link refers to the outdated WIF 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own Custom Security Token Service leveraging the underneath SQL Server database. You will have to define your scopes and Claims that needs to be shared after user does a Single Sign On. Here are some links to some articles below that has helped me build mine. I am pretty sure by following the below links you will be able to build a custom STS catering to your needs.

WIF : http://chris.59north.com/post/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC

http://www.primaryobjects.com/2013/08/08/using-single-sign-on-with-windows-identity-foundation-in-mvc-net/

Answer (score -1):

Care to explain why @paullem's answer was deleted?

It is in fact the correct answer!

The question is about an STS that authenticates using a SQL DB. That is **EXACTLY** what [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer) does.

Since it's open source, you can customize it any way you want or else use it as a guide.

So to repeat the answer - "Take a look at Thinktecture.IdentityServer........".

**Update**

You want a custom STS that supports SAML protocol and authenticates against a SQL DB?

WIF won't do this for you.

You need to look at something like Shibboleth or simpleSAMLphp but they are not .NET based.

Or take IdentityServer and add a SAML stack to it.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Be warned: This is not a trivial exercise!

Comment: The problem is that IdentityServer3 (if I understand) is based on the OpendID protocol. Our clients are using SAML2.0 protocol.

Comment: It's based on OpenID Connect, OAuth2 and WS-Federation. No - it doesn't support SAML. Why didn't you specify this in the question?

Comment: Ok. Sorry I did not thought it was necessary given that WIF supports both SAML and OpenID. In my case I have to be SAML compliant.
So, you don't have any other idea?
Thank you.

Comment: No - WIF does not support the SAML protocol (only SAML tokens). It does not support OpenID either. It only supports WS-Federation.

Comment: Implement an SAML Identity Provider is way more complicated than a Service Provider one. Usually the time you need to spend on it to support all possible real life use cases will cost you more than buying a commercial product. Product like http://safewhere.com/products/safewhere-identify-server/ provides the necessary extensible point for you to authenticate users again any stores. Full disclosure: I work for that product :)

Comment: Actually WIF is supporting SAML.

Comment: Why the downvote? WIF does not support the SAML protocol. It supports SAML tokens. That's completely different.